# Save a browsed file to a pre-defined folder using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a WinForm Application using c#. I am using a button to browse for an image file (.jpeg or .bmp). When the user browses the file and clicks ok, on the click of another "Proceed or Update" button, I want that the browsed file should be renamed and saved to a predefined directory where all image files will be saved by default, without much user interaction!

How can I achieve this? I have used openFileDialog for browsing the file, but dont know what else to do.

Comment: There are two ways of doing this. One way would be to copy the file using File.Copy, and the other would be to get the load the image stream into your program and save it elsewhere. Do you want the user to be able to edit the image, or is it simply a diret copy?

Comment: a direct copy but with desired name, i mean i need to rename the file according to a naming convention!

Comment: I've posted the code to show how to use File.Copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//detination filename
string newFileName = @"C:\NewImages\NewFileName.jpg";    

// if the user presses OK instead of Cancel
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    //get the selected filename
    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName; 

    //copy the file to the new filename location and overwrite if it already exists 
    //(set last parameter to false if you don't want to overwrite)
    System.IO.File.Copy(filename, newFileName, true);
}
```

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) on the Copy method.

Comment: can i specify the complete path as the second parameter?

Comment: Yes, the first and second parameters can use absolute or relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to implement a copy function that can make unique file names:

```
private void CopyWithUniqueName(string source, 
                                string targetPath,
                                string targetFileName)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(targetFileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(targetFileName);

    string target = File.Exists(Path.Combine(targetPath, targetFileName);
    for (int i=1; File.Exists(target); ++i)
    {
        target = Path.Combine(targetPath, String.Format("{0} ({1}){2}",
            targetFileName, i, extension));
    }

    File.Copy(source, target);
}
```

Then you can use it, suppose `defaultTargetPath` is the default target file where to copy images and `defaultFileName` is the default file name for images:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return;

    CopyWithUniqueName(openFileDialog1.FileName, 
        defaultTargetPath, defaultFileName);
}
```

In case of multiple selection:

```
foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    CopyWithUniqueName(fileName, 
        defaultTargetPath, defaultFileName);
}
```

You'll get this (suppose `defaultFileName` is "Image.png"):

```
Source   Target
A.png    Image.png
B.png    Image (1).png
C.png    Image (2).png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the File.Copy()-method. Just put the predefined directory and the new filename as the destination parameter.

For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx)